# How to show rectangle around each segments..and measure x and y coordinates of image

Tags: c#, rtd

I want to count no. of segments in rtd images and have to draw rectangle around each of object .Also i have to measure x and y coordinates in c#

Comment: Please don't use wrong tag. c++ is irrelevant here.

Comment: i also want this in cpp also...so i tagged it

Comment: sorry..its an rdt..its an image type